# Integration android and instagram

Tags: android, instagram

I need to catch the entire list of followers in Instagram and import for my app. This is possible ?

Comment: you need to show your effort... what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Through the [instagram api](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/), it allows a request for followers through `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by`. Note that authentication is required before this method will return any data.

From there, you should get a JSON response that contains all of the followers, that you can handle however you'd like within your app.